# Problemas com menu vertical bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Boa noite

O meu vertical na barra de navegação não aparece corretamente quando ajusto a página para um tamanho menor de dispositivo. O que ocorre?

Agradecendo desde já

Segue link

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sys_dan/tkc8hh27/)

Answer (score 0):

Ola, sua ul esta configurada de maneira errada!
ja que está usando bootstrap experimenta colocar esse menu. Só tem que alterar os titulos dos menus..

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica. Estou dando os primeiros passos com bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

seu problema esta no css nessa parte:

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid @carousel-indicators-border-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Você esta aplicando um estilo que era pra ser apenas para o carousel em todas a li, inclusive nas do menu. Esta propriedade `display: inline-block;` faz com que elas se comportem de tal forma "estranha".

Comment: Muito obrigado, meu amigo. Ainda estou dando os primeiros passos com bootstrap.